# Warning en Android Manifest después de actualización

Tags: android

Se ha actualizado mi Android Studio y desde entonces me sale un warning en AndroidManifest

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Aunque funciona correctamente, me gustaría saber el ¿por qué?

Comment: Sería importante especificar que Warning se muestra, ¿lo podrías agregar?

Comment: Hola me pareció interesante tu pregunta ya que hoy también actualice mi android studio, al parecer ahora si no colocas algunas orientación siempre se quedara en Portrait (lo he probado hace unos minutos) , según documentación te dice que si no colocas "fullSensor" nunca podrá tomar las 4 orientaciones.Te dejo el link y parte de la documentación: > "fullSensor": El sensor de orientación del dispositivo determina cualquiera de las cuatro orientaciones posibles. Es similar a "sensor", con la excepción de que aquí se permite cualquiera de las cuatro posibles orientaciones de pantalla, independient